# iOS 13 : How to prevent app from getting killed in background?

Tags: ios13, background-application

I am working on an app where my app need to get location in background and update it to the server. It was working fine for earlier iOS versions. But after release of iOS 13, my app is getting killed in the background. I have checked so many workarounds but have found any feasible solution. It is having "Background Processing" capability.

Any help is most welcome!!!

Comment: If this is happening on iOS 13.2 it's not your fault. This version of iOS has a bug that causes the system to aggressively kill apps in the background. Try on iOS 13.3 or versions before 13.2

Comment: @donnywals Did you check on iOS 13.3 that background apps are not getting killed by os? Just need to confirm.

Comment: @KirtiParghi, I have checked in iOS 13.3, it still kills in background after sometimes. Is there any solution you got so far ?

Comment: my app also gets killed in background if I spend more than 30 seconds in background, I also checked with latest iOS13.3 version too

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed have you found any solution ? i am facing same issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Only Music Apps or Downloader form internet apps ("Completing a Long-Running Task in the Background") will remain in the background all other apps will be killed after some time.

Comment: Do we have any documentation from apple for this comment ?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started please have a look i

Answer (score 0):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210393#1322
- [iOS 13.2.2] Fixes an issue that could cause apps to quit unexpectedly when running in the background

Comment: I think this issue still exists even in iOS 13.3 too

Answer (score 0):

Crash may be due to a background task leak. In my application, some SDKs don't use the background task correctly. Because it was killed by the watchdog, debugging will not appear, you can print beginBackgroundTask and endBackgroundTask during debugging. If there is a mismatch, a leak occurs.

I wrote a category to hook background task related methods to avoid leaking being killed by watchdog：https://github.com/ruanjx/MPIBackgroundTaskProtection

More information about background task：https://medium.com/swlh/handling-background-tasks-in-ios-13-67f717d94b3d